# Sencha touch unable to register store using StoreManager after using unregister method on same store

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am creating a store using rest service.whenever I unregister the store and register again it gives me undefined in console for the store and undefined for getProxy().

Code Snippet:

Controller: (where I am destroying my view and unregistering Store)

```
var xyz = Ext.getStore('xyz');
xyz.removeAll();
console.log(xyz);
Ext.StoreManager.unregister(xyz);
```

Controller: (Where I am creating View and Loading Store via Rest Service)

```
var xyz= Ext.getStore('xyz');
console.log(xyz);------------------(undefined)
Ext.StoreManager.register(xyz);
console.log(xyz);------------------(undefined)
xyz.getProxy().setUrl(urixyz);
```

Last line of code where I am trying to get Proxy give me error for undefined of store.

Please let me know how to register the store if we have unregistered it and want to use it again..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to recreate the store and register it.